# Change JSON data received

Tags: python, json

I am sending json file to my device over a MQTT broker.

**The Python script to send the json data is**

```
def send_data():
    print("Inside Send data function")
    jsonFile = open("dataFile.json", "r")  # Open the JSON file for reading
    data = json.load(jsonFile2)  # Read the JSON into the buffer
    jsonFile.close()  # Close the JSON file
    data_out = json.dumps(data)
    print(data_out)
    client.publish(topic2, data_out, 1, True)    #Publish on topic on MQTT broker
```

**The Output of this segment of script is**

```
In send video AD function
{"link": "www.youtube.com", "link_id": "ad_1234"}
```

**The JSON file to be send**

```
{"link": "www.google.com", "link_id": "id_1234"}
```

**_______________________________________________________________________________**

**The Python script to receive JSON data**

```
def receive_data():    
    log.debug("Subscribing to topic")
    ret = client.subscribe(topic, qos=1)
    logging.info("Subscribed return = " + str(ret))
    with open('file.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
    statusFile = open('file.json', 'r')
    status = json.load(statusFile)
    statusFile.close()
```

**The output of the File.json is**

```
"{\"link\": \"www.youtube.com\", \"link_id\": \"ad_1234\"}"
```

I don't know why am I receiving in this format with extra "" and /. I want to receive my data in the same way as I am sending. How to do this?

Comment: In addition to my answer: It doesn't seem like you're doing anything with `ret`.

Comment: I am using ret to see the status, if client.subscribe was successful of not... forgot to remove that line .. here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're receiving a JSON-encoded string. JSON is a specification of how to turn certain kinds of objects into strings or byte sequences. If you want to turn a JSON-encoded string back into an object, use `json.loads` on it:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("{\"link\": \"www.youtube.com\", \"link_id\": \"ad_1234\"}")
{"link": "www.youtube.com", "link_id": "ad_1234"}
```

Answer (score 1):

python 3.6+ is pretty, it is required by the following code:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
def send_data():
    print("Inside Send data function")
    fname = "dataFile.json"  # the JSON file
    """
    # just read the file, no need to json loads and dumps
    data = json.loads(Path(fname).read_text())  # Read file and loads
    data_out = json.dumps(data)
    """
    data_out = Path(fname).read_text()
    print(data_out)
    client.publish(topic2, data_out, 1, True)    #Publish on topic on MQTT broker

def receive_data():    
    log.debug("Subscribing to topic")
    ret = client.subscribe(topic, qos=1)
    logging.info(f"Subscribed return = {ret}")
    fname = "file.json"
    Path(fname).write_text(data)
    status = json.loads(data)
```